# Multiprocessing Python 3 - Check individial processes have ended

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

What I am trying to achieve is multiple processes running at the exact same time and once finished continue my program or call a different function. At the moment the code outputs the following:

```
2

3

1

[<Process(Process-1, started)>, <Process(Process-2, started)>, <Process(Process-
3, started)>]

Terminated

Terminated

Terminated
[Finished in 4.1s]
```

So I know the start function is being called 3 times and running simultaneously but how come the process is only terminated right at the end? Surely the output would be:

```
2

Terminated

3

Terminated

1

Terminated
```

If anyone could shed any light on this I would be grateful. Thanks in advance.

```
import multiprocessing, time

def start(counter):
    if(counter == 0):
        time.sleep(4)
        print(1)
    elif(counter == 1):
        time.sleep(0.2)
        print(2)
    elif(counter==2):
        time.sleep(3)
        print(3)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    processes = []
    for x in range(0, 3):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=start, args=(x,))
        processes.append(p)
        p.start()

    print(processes)
    while len(processes) > 0:
        for process in processes:
            if not process.is_alive():
                processes.remove(process)
                print ("Terminated")

    #Program continues once all the processes have finished
```

Comment: Instead of handling all the processes yourself, you could use `multiprocessing.Pool` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Move your `print "terminated"?` inside the start-function, after the if-elif.

The main process cannot start detecting termination until it has launched all your processes. Hence you will never see `"terminated"` interleaved with the counters.